SIGSEGV, problematic frame V libjvm.so, Program terminated with signal SIGABRT
So I have been trying to host a minecraft forge server from a dedicated PC running on Debian 12 and using java 17.0.11
Java Runtime Error:
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa19ace7860, pid=2664, tid=2685
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.11+7) (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xee7860]
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/kestrel/Documents/server_4/hs_err_pid2664.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted


hs_err:
https://pastebin.com/SR7kZBwm
gdb output from core dump
GNU gdb (Debian 13.1-3) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
"/home/kestrel/Documents/server_4/run.sh": not in executable format: file format not recognized

warning: Can't open file /home/kestrel/.cache/JNA/temp/jna17624599351093677515.tmp (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing

warning: Can't open file /tmp/hsperfdata_kestrel/3034 (deleted) during file-backed mapping note processing
[New LWP 3062]
[New LWP 3037]
[New LWP 3048]
[New LWP 3049]
[New LWP 3061]
[New LWP 3056]
[New LWP 3035]
[New LWP 3050]
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
[New LWP 3039]
[New LWP 3038]
[New LWP 3076]
[New LWP 3080]
[New LWP 3137]
[New LWP 3065]
[New LWP 3132]
[New LWP 3044]
[New LWP 3091]
[New LWP 3043]
[New LWP 3060]
[New LWP 3099]
[New LWP 3090]
[New LWP 3034]
[New LWP 3047]
[New LWP 3141]
[New LWP 3104]
[New LWP 3092]
[New LWP 3098]
[New LWP 3095]
[New LWP 3121]
[New LWP 3036]
[New LWP 3063]
[New LWP 3052]
[New LWP 3077]
[New LWP 3055]
[New LWP 3108]
[New LWP 3100]
[New LWP 3125]
[New LWP 3040]
[New LWP 3093]
[New LWP 3140]
[New LWP 3089]
[New LWP 3058]
[New LWP 3109]
[New LWP 3102]
[New LWP 3094]
[New LWP 3041]
[New LWP 3110]
[New LWP 3101]
[New LWP 3045]
[New LWP 3118]
[New LWP 3117]
[New LWP 3119]
[New LWP 3139]
[New LWP 3057]
[New LWP 3059]
[New LWP 3120]
[New LWP 3042]
[New LWP 3046]
[New LWP 3053]
[New LWP 3096]
[New LWP 3097]
[New LWP 3138]
Core was generated by `java @user_jvm_args.txt @libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.20.1-47.3.0/unix_'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f22022f1e2c in ?? ()
[Current thread is 1 (LWP 3062)]


Previously I was using Java 22 but kept getting issues and decided to try switching java versions, this worked to a little while before this started happening again.
The first time I run the run.sh after a fresh reboot, the terminal just kind of stops midway through and won't do anything, so I have to kill the process. Anytime after that the aforementioned error occurs

[edit] your question to add a [mre],

I get [HTTP status] 403 (forbidden) when I try to open your [pastebin] link.

It looks like the crash is occurring in the G1 garbage collector. ~~Sounds like heap corruption to me.~~ Edit: you say you're killing the process, so that may have some strange interaction with something else going on.
